# If input month is missing get the next nearest smallest or equal too number from DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I need a help in python where if a sequence of month is missing as per user input then it will give the output rows as either equal too or nearest smallest numbers from Months in all VIN.

CurrentDf:

| VIN | Total Age | Months | Monthly Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | 10 | 00 | 1513 |
| v1 | 10 | 05 | 1108 |
| v1 | 10 | 07 | 4330 |
| v1 | 10 | 09 | 7121 |
| v2 | 08 | 01 | 1998 |
| v2 | 08 | 04 | 4997 |
| v2 | 08 | 05 | 8528 |
| v2 | 08 | 06 | 1783 |
| v2 | 08 | 07 | 9628 |
| v2 | 08 | 08 | 2082 |

Age = [int(x) for x in input('Please enter Months?= ').split(',')]

If UserInput: 6

outputDF:

| VIN | Total Age | Months | Monthly Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | 10 | 05 | 1108 |
| v2 | 08 | 06 | 1783 |

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
age = 6

x = df[df["Months"] <= age].groupby("VIN", as_index=False).tail(1)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  VIN  Total Age  Months  Monthly Revenue
1  v1         10       5             1108
7  v2          8       6             1783
```

Comment: got error "('Lengths must match to compare', (560497,), (1,))" .